# Validate if user exist with Firebase and Swift but with FirebaseDatabase - not FIRDatabase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new in swift and at this moment i trying to make validation if user exist in my iOS app.
I found a lot of answers but every answer has solution with FIRDatabase. Im using the newest version and it looks different. 
At first i must start from FirebaseDatabase but what after? How to make similiar thing to this:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

         databaseRef.child("Users").observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild(self.usernameTextField.text!){

                print("true rooms exist")

            }else{

                print("false room doesn't exist")
            }
```

Somebody can prof me this is a proper way?

```
let databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild(userEmail){
            print("OK")
        } else {
            print("NOPE")
        }
    })
```

But no effect in console.

Comment: I believe all they did was removing `FIR` prefix. Did you try that?

Comment: I updated some details @KirilS.

Comment: Have you read firebase docs 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: snapshot.hasChild will look for child not value `{email: 'someemail' }`, if we take this case `email` is a child and `somemail` is a value, what you are doing is something like this one

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON of `/Users` (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). In addition, if you show `userEmail` as a hard-coded value, it makes it easier for us to see what's going on.

Comment: Thats the point, now i can verify if email exist. Thanks!